# Is there a term for an animal that died of a disease?

Tags: terminology, animals

In Russian animals that died of a disease can be translated as fallen animals e.g. fallen sheep.

Is there a similar term in English?

Comment: Nothing is coming to mind.

Comment: Thanks, I also could not think of anything. The closest term was animals that died of a disease.

Comment: There are terms like *mortality* and *morbidity*, but they describe the state, vs being an adjective on the animal.  I gather you want something that could be used like "dead-from-disease sheep", but again nothing comes to mind.

Comment: Yep, dead-from-disease-sheep. Someone suggested carrion which is a carcass of an animal that died of either a disease or natural causes but I think it's usually in reference to wild or stray animals rather than domesticated kinds.

Comment: 'Diseased sheep' refers to sheep that are still alive; I don't think there's a simple term for 'sheep that died because they were diseased'.

Comment: Not sure -- *died of natural causes*?

Comment: If you mean specifically livestock, I don't think that happens very often in the US; typically, a diseased animal would be put down before it could die on its own (and, more pertinently, hopefully before it could infect other animals). The term for that would be *destroyed* animals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term for farm animals that have died of a disease is, in fact, *[fallen stock](https://www.farmweb.co.uk/tips-advice/glossary/#glossaryF)*:-

> Animals that have died on the farm. These need to be removed as
>   on-farm burial is prohibited

So you would have *fallen sheep*, *fallen cows*, *fallen chickens* (for all I know). A guide as to what to do with them can be found [here](https://www.daera-ni.gov.uk/articles/fallen-stock-guidance).

Comment: This seems somewhat orthogonal to what's being asked here. At least according to that definition, an animal who died in a fight on the farm would be considered fallen, whereas a wild animal that dies of a disease in the woods would not. It also sounds rather jargony and technical—I would assume, not knowing of this specific meaning, that a fallen animal was one that had died in battle (mostly, I suppose, applicable to horses in the old days and more generally in Narnia and such places).

Comment: It may be jargon, but it's [definitely the official term](https://www.gov.uk/search?q=fallen+stock)

Comment: I think it's used mainly in the UK and maybe it's time other English speaking countries adopted it too :)